# Changing my navigation based on date

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like my site to display different seasonal projects based on the date. Currently, I call the 'Top Winter Projects' section of my right navigation with the following code:

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_favorites.php'); ?>
```

Is there a way that I could use a php include based on date? So if its January 14, call /stub_favorites.php, but if its March 10, call stub_favorites1.php? I'm new to php so bear with me.

My website is as followed: http://www.merrimentdesign.com

Comment: Can you cut it down to one include per month or calendar week (easy), or do you need specific start and end dates (a bit more complex)?

Comment: Yes, if per month works then similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784811/php-setting-image-based-on-season

Comment: I could do per month. Thans for the reference.

Comment: you Could regroup month to almost mimic seasons using a switch condition : switch(date('n')){case 1: case 2: case 3: include menu1.php; break; case 4: case 5: case 6: include menu2.php; break;} and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PHPs Date/Time Functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

You can do something like:

```
if (date('m/d/Y') < date('m/d/Y', strtotime("12/1/2011"))) {
    //Display something
}
else {
    //Display something different
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most dead easy way to display one include per month:

```
<?php
   $filename = "month".date("n").".php";
   if (file_exists($filename)) include($filename);
```

then add files:

```
month1.php
month2.php
month3.php
```

the right file will be included for each month. The script will fail silently if a month does not exist. To make this work for calendar weeks instead, use `date("W");`. A full reference of date parameters can be found in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).