# how to call a seperate php file each day of the year?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am a beginner in PHP and would like to load a daily meditation every day that is specific to that day.

So on January 1st, I would call the quote from `1_1.php` and on the 2nd `1_2.php`, and so on until February 1st which would call `2_1.php` and on the 2nd `2_2.php` on the third `2_3.php`.

Is this possible and how hard would it be?

It would also be acceptable to have 365 files where it just called the next one in order every twenty-four hours, or one file with 365 lines and called a different line every day, but I do not know how to do this as I only know how to build in html and design so any help or advice would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing my navigation based on date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763109/changing-my-navigation-based-on-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would most definitely not use 365 different files. It might be sensible to use a database, but since these seem to be one-liners and you are new to PHP, the simples method is to them in a big array.  The downside of this is that the whole array will be read and parsed on each page load.  But I wouldn't worry about the performance of that until it becomes a problem.

```
$meditations = array(
  '1-Jan' => "Some meditation for today",
  '2-Jan' => "Some meditation for tomorrow",
  ...
  ...
  '28-Dec' => "Something for today",
  '29-Dec' => "Something for tomorrow",
  '30-Dec' => "Something for tomorrow2",
  '31-Dec' => "Something for new year's eve"
);
```

Then access them as:

```
echo $meditations[date('j-M')];
// Today will output
//something for today
```

If you prefer, insted of using the format `dd-Mon` for array keys, you can use numeric months as in:

```
array('28-12' => "something for today");
// Access as:
echo $meditations[date('j-m')];
```

The complete bit to include inside your PHP page (note it will need to be a .php page, rather than .html) is:

```
<?php
$meditations = array(
   '1-1' => "Some meditation for today",
   '2-1' => "Some meditation for tomorrow",
   // etc....
);
echo $meditations[date('j-m')];
?>
```

You can alternatively store the huge array in its own file called meditations.php, and include it:

File meditations.php

```
<?php
$meditations = array(
   '1-1' => "Some meditation for today",
   '2-1' => "Some meditation for tomorrow",
   // etc....
);
?>
```

Main file:

```
<?php 
include("meditations.php");
echo $meditations[date('j-m')];
?>
```

To include this in a plain HTML page (not .php), you'll need an `<iframe>`. Assuming your PHP is working correctly in a file called `meditations.php`, call the `<iframe>` like this:

```
<iframe src='meditations.php' />
```

Comment: thanks so much you guys that was a huge help!!!!!! many good wishes for the new year!

Comment: @user1120049 Happy to help. If you're satisfied with an answer, please mark it as accepted by clicking on its checkmark. And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: `<?

$meditations = array(

  '1-1' => "Some meditation for today",
  '2-1' => "Some meditation for tomorrow",
  '3-1' => "Some meditation for that day",
  '4-1' => "Some meditation for tomorrow2",
  '5-1' => "Some meditation for today test",
  '28-12' => "Something for todayagain",
  '29-12' => "Something for tomorrowagain",
  '30-12' => "Something for today test2",
  '31-12' => "Something for new year's eve"


);

echo date("d-m")

echo $meditations[date('d-m')];

// Today will output

//something for today

?>`

Comment: okay so i can't figure out how to post in code format on here - but anyways would you look at that and tell me if it is adequate ? dreamweaver is saying there is an error right here "echo $meditations[date('d-m')];" and what do i need to put in the html page to call it? will this do? "  <script src="http://onlinedailymeditations.com/newarray.php"></script>"

Comment: See edit above. Instead of `'d-m'`, you will use `'j-m'` for dates like `'3-1'`.  Dreamweaver is reporting an error because you are missing a `;` after `echo date("d-m")`

Comment: okay so i got the code all working great with some test quotes - and tested it here - http://writecodeonline.com/php/ but i don't know how to get it to output into my html page! is quite frustrating and annoying i have been trying for days but it refuses to work!

Comment: @user1120049 Does your html page have a .html extension or .php? If it is .html, it won't be parsed as PHP code.  You can, however include it in an `<iframe>` in the html page. see forthcoming edit above...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database personally, but this is possible if you wanted to do it:

```
<?php
include(date("n_j").".php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it, is to have one PHP file which loads data from some sort of storage (most preferably database table) and each day load a record for that particular day.

If you want to stick with your multiple files you can do:

```
<?php
    $filename = date("m")."_".date("d").".php";
   if (file_exists($filename)) include($filename);
?>
```